# Old PHP4 : method to recover variable from URL

Tags: php, variables, url, php4

I have to reinstall a really old intranet for a customer on a brand new machine with the latest version of Debian.

Before I begin : It is really old code, I know it is depracated, but it is not question to change anything to the code. My customer is not concerned about security holes.

I compiled PHP 4.4.9 and bound it to this website using ISPConfig.
Everything seems to work fine, except that PHP doesn't seem to recover variables from URL.

Example or URL :

> http://intranet/?action=connect&form[login]=john&form[password]=123456

Example of code :

```
if ( isset( $action ) && $action=="connect")
  {
  if ( empty( $form[login] ) || 
        empty( $form[password] ) ) 
   {
...
```

Problem is : variables "action", "form[login]" and "form[password]" remain empty.

I know I already encountered this problem once, and was able to fix it without altering the code, but I can't remember how. 
It must be a option to enable or disable somewhere in PHP.

Comment: Check if `register_globals` is enabled in the php.ini.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked like a charm !! :)